# Twitter Bootstrap rtl rating stars

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap to build my site UI.

I want to create a stars rating page.

I want it to be right to left (meaning one star is chosen to the right)

I see my best opetion is to use Jquery-UI plugin, as bootstrap doesn't have such a tool?

How to make the rating direction: rtl ?

In addition, how can I adjust the stars to be yellow and not red

(both on hover and after selection) ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also use bootstrap. This morning I started looking into star ratings and came across the [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) site. Here you'll find a working example of Star Ratings within bootstrap.

The [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/) site provides the needed CSS with a good explanation of what it is doing.

*I apologize for the lack of links below. As I am "new poster" on stackoverflow I can only include two hyperlinks. So you'll need to paste the gists into the dabble.com URL to see them.* (someone please vote my reputation up so I can post more links :)

You can find working examples at the dabblet.com site to play with it a bit before bringing it into your cown code base. The css-tricks dabblet is at https://gist.github.com/1709019
.

There are several other dabblets you may want to review:

@chriscoyier has a different implementation at 
https://gist.github.com/1718992
. You can change from LTR to RTL in this implementaion by changing float:right; to float:left;

@mprogano has an even more concise version at https://gist.github.com/1712123. You can change from LTR to RTL using direction: rtl;

Some of the dabble examples allow you to change the star colors, others are using images so you'd have to create your own images to change color.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I prefer @chriscoyier's solution because it uses real input fields as they're meant to be used, so no need for extra JS bindings. One thing to point out though: in the dabblet.com HTML code, the order of the input fields needs to be reversed in order to link the labels to the correct radio button (right now clicking on the 4th star will actually select the star-2 radio button). The labels are reversed because they're right-floated.

Answer (score 13):

Got a bit inspired and tried a litte something along the lines of "less code". Also added a js function to alert the number of stars selected (which of course easily could be changed to do something more fancy).

http://jsfiddle.net/RpfLa/135/

```
<div class="star-rating"><s><s><s><s><s></s></s></s></s></s></div>
<div class="star-rating-rtl"><s><s><s><s><s></s></s></s></s></s></div>
```

Have fun!

Edit: See also http://jsfiddle.net/RpfLa/400/ for a preset rating.

```
<s class="rated"></s>
```

Comment: Awesome!
Pretty neat code! Can you please show me how would you leave the stars highlighted after click? (ie. If I give a 3 star-rating; 3 stars should be filled) If you can help me out with this would be really great. Thanks for the jsfiddle you posted, it's really helpful

Comment: Thanks! One way to it would be to set class="active" on the right number of stars like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RpfLa/400/   Another would be to set class="rating-3star" on the parent element, but that would require much more css to accomplish the same.

Comment: Fantastic! thank you for your quick reply! I can certainly use your code to work my way through what I want to accomplish, really useful.
One important question: Why do you nest the <s> tags like that? I found it weird on close inspection

Comment: No problems. The nesting makes all stars trigger their :hover when the last one is hovered.

Comment: Awesome work on this rating system, I had a slight issue with having multiple elements in a single page, I decided once the rating on an item has been made to replace the stars with a text representation of the rating like the alert in the fiddle. To do this and allow multiple rating elements on the page I simply replaced the alert JS with `$(this).replaceWith(numStars + (numStars == 1 ? " star" : " stars!"));`

Comment: hi @Victor   Great code, but can the the marked stars remain red color even not mouse hovering them??? I really need that. thx~!!!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple pure CSS solution for star rating for font icons of twitter bootstrap. To use with any other font icon like fontawesome etc just need to change the class name in HTML

HTML:

```
<div class="rating"
  <span id="5" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
  <span id="4" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
  <span id="3" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
  <span id="2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
  <span id="1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rating span {
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right; //remove 'float right' for right to left
}
.rating span:hover, .rating span:hover ~ span{
  color: red; //gold or any other color 
}
```

Jquery to capture rating on click

```
$('.rating span').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

Here is the [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/anuradhabajpai/L5KPw/7/)

Comment: where is the 'rtl' part

Comment: 'rtl' is 'right to left' which is controlled by float property in .rating span mentioned above...

Comment: How to include a form to post rating?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem some time ago and ended up creating a little plugin. I've recently updated it for Bootstrap 3:

https://github.com/javiertoledo/bootstrap-rating-input

You're welcome to send feedback or pull requests :-)

Best regards!

Comment: Does exactly what was needed, with **RTL** support. Thanks a lot, just had to change some classes to make it Bootstrap 3 compatible though, now its working fine.

Comment: Awesome, I'm interested to review what was failing in Bootstrap 3 and what changes you needed to do, if you submit a PR I'll take a look and fix the widget for future releases. Thanks!

Comment: My sincerest apologies, actually I meant to say that, I had to tweak to make it compatible with bootstrap 2.xx and said vice versa.. damn hangover from last night...:D

Answer (score 1):

Considering the issues faced in various plugins - here is a [Bootstrap JQuery Star rating plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating) I created with various configurable options (demos for scenarios are included within). Some of these are inspired by various ideas (e.g. by Victor) and other user needs. I think you could try this for your scenarios mentioned and let know.

Uses Bootstrap 3.x glyphicons and pure CSS as much possible, includes RTL support, supports plugin events and methods. You can refer the [source here](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating).

EDIT: The plugin now supports fractional star ratings with few other enhancements as well.